# Bluetooth earbuds turning off after 5 minutes

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I have the Tronsmart Spunky Beat True Wireless Bluetooth Earbuds, which works fine for Windows and Android, but turns off exactly 5 minutes after paired on Linux. Until that point, it works fine and I cant switch to HSP and cant use the mic. Does anyone know a driver, a workaround or anything I could use?

I checked the Arch Wiki :) with no help, disabled pulseaudio auto-turn-off device on idle feature and restarted pulseaudio, but it's still doing this.

I've tried every distro out there.

Comment: did you try contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: They didn't answer back.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Tronsmart Onyx Neo TWS Earbuds. Solved it finally with enabling HFP/HSP profile:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#HFP_not_working_with_PulseAudio

For Ubuntu you can install ofono by:

```
sudo apt-get install ofono
```

But you need to compile the phonesim by cloning this git: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ofono/phonesim.git/

You will need qtbase5-dev and qtdeclarative5-dev (which also depends on libqt5quick5) packages to compile.

Just clone it and run `./bootstrap-configure` then make then sudo make install. then go ahead with archwiki.